# SwiftUI: Filtered list indices are not corresponding to new list

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have a `Country` model and then a JSON list of countries.  I have creating the list by using a `ForEach`.  If the search box is empty, the value of `filteredCountries` is just the whole list, otherwise the list only contains countries that include whats in the search box.
The problem is that when the list is filtered and I click to `favorite` an item, the wrong country is favorited. The indices don't match the filtered items, they still go in sequential order: `0,1,2,3` etc.

**Country**

```
import Foundation

struct Country: Codable, Identifiable {
    var id: String {image}
    let display_name: String
    let searchable_names: [String]
    let image: String
    var favorite: Bool
    var extended: Bool
}
```

**ContentView**

```
var filteredCountries : [Country] {
    if (searchText.isEmpty) {
        return countries;
    } else {
        return countries.filter { $0.display_name.contains(searchText) }
    }
}

          NavigationView {
                ScrollView {
                    ForEach(Array(filteredCountries.enumerated()), id: \.1.id) { (index,country) in
                        
                        LazyVStack {
                            ZStack(alignment: .bottom) {
                                Image("\(country.image)-bg")
                                    .resizable()
                                    .scaledToFit()
                                    .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
                                    .overlay(Rectangle().opacity(0.2))
                                    .mask(
                                        LinearGradient(gradient: Gradient(colors: [Color.black, Color.black.opacity(0)]), startPoint: .center, endPoint: .bottom)
                                    )
                                
                                
                                HStack {
                                    NavigationLink(
                                        destination: CountryView(country: country),
                                        label: {
                                            HStack {
                                                Image(country.image)
                                                    .resizable()
                                                    .frame(width: 50, height: 50)
                                                Text(country.display_name)
                                                    .foregroundColor(Color.black)
                                                    .padding(.leading)
                                                Spacer()
                                            }
                                            .padding(.top, 12.0)
                                            
                                        }
                                    ).buttonStyle(FlatLinkStyle())
                                    if country.favorite {
                                        Image(systemName: "heart.fill").foregroundColor(.red).onTapGesture {
                                            print(country)
                                            countries[index].favorite.toggle()
                                        }
                                        .padding(.top, 12)
                                    } else {
                                        Image(systemName: "heart").foregroundColor(.red).onTapGesture {
                                            print(country)

                                            countries[index].favorite.toggle()
                                        }
                                        .padding(.top, 12)
                                    }
                                    
                                }
                                .padding(.horizontal, 16.0)
                            }
                        }
                        .padding(.bottom, country.extended ? 220 : 0)
                        .onTapGesture {
                            withAnimation(.easeInOut(duration: 0.4)) {
                                self.countries[index].extended.toggle();
                                
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                .frame(maxWidth: bounds.size.width)
                .navigationTitle("Countries")
                .font(Font.custom("Avenir-Book", size: 28))


            }
            .navigationViewStyle(StackNavigationViewStyle())
            .searchable(text: $searchText, placement: .navigationBarDrawer(displayMode: .always), prompt: "Search Country")
```

Comment: Please include a [mre]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've made a simple demo you can try out. The most notable thing is `filteredCountry` being of type `[Binding<Country>]` - this allows us to mutate the element because it is a `Binding`. In the `List`/`ForEach` loop, use `$country` because we are passing in a `Binding`.

Code:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var countries: [Country] = ["Canada", "England", "France", "Germany", "US"]
    @State private var search = ""

    private var filteredCounties: [Binding<Country>] {
        if search.isEmpty {
            return $countries.map { $0 }
        } else {
            return $countries.filter { $country in
                country.name.lowercased().contains(search.lowercased())
            }
        }
    }

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List(filteredCounties) { $country in
                HStack {
                    Text(country.name)

                    Spacer()

                    Image(systemName: country.isFavorite ? "heart.fill" : "heart")
                        .foregroundColor(.red)
                        .onTapGesture {
                            country.isFavorite.toggle()
                        }
                }
            }
        }
        .navigationViewStyle(.stack)
        .searchable(text: $search, prompt: "Canada")
    }
}
```

The structure below of `Country` isn't so relevant, but is here for completeness:

```
struct Country: Identifiable, ExpressibleByStringLiteral {
    let id = UUID()
    let name: String
    var isFavorite = false

    init(stringLiteral value: StringLiteralType) {
        name = value
    }
}
```

Result:

[image: Result]

Comment: @Fogmeister This isn't my question... I was just providing a demo for the _other_ person who made the question, of how to do it (in a [mre] way). This is working code.

Comment: Ah, sorry, my bad 

Comment: @Fogmeister Nw, probably the wording in the first sentence haha

Comment: thank you so much, this was very informative and I appreciate you going through the trouble of making a demo like this!

Answer (score 0):

in the
`ForEach(Array(filteredCountries.enumerated()), id: \.1.id) { (index,country) in ....`

the `index` refers to the index of the "new" array consisting of just the filtered countries,
not the original array of all the countries. To access the original array items,
you could use the country id, such as:

```
    if let ndx = countries.firstIndex(where: {$0.id == country.id}) {
        countries[ndx].favorite.toggle()
     }
```

instead of:

```
 countries[index].favorite.toggle()
```

Comment: A very realistic solution, but it's worth warning that for a large array (which it likely is for listing all the countries) this can become comparatively slow due to the search. Still a fine solution

Comment: Actually, will that work? Looks like you are mutating `cntry` which can't be mutated, since it is a `struct` but declared with `let`. `var` wouldn't solve the problem either because it's still a local copy.

Comment: updated my answer. Note, all countries would be about 250, not a large array by any measure.

Comment: would just using `countries[country.id].favorite.toggle()` work?  Since`country.id` would always be referring to the correct country, rather than the list index

Comment: no, that would not work. `country.id` is not the same as an index into the array of countries.